# Combining treatment as usual and experimental placebo control groups in one meta analysis

Tags: meta-analysis

I'm conducting a sr and meta analysis of interventions that target children with ADHD in school settings.  The studies reviewed include both treatment as usual comparisons and experiments placebo controls.  Can these types of studies be combined in a single meta analytic synthesis?  I wondered about conducting a moderator analysis using design type as a predictor variable?
Any comments welcome!

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it's probably best not to do this: Placebo effects can be large.

One thing you could do, though, is look at the meta-analysis with the two types combined and see about heterogeneity. You could look at $I^2$ (a good idea in any meta-analysis) and also meta-regression, with "type of comparison study" as an independent variable.

Answer (score 1):

It is common for systematic reviews to be looking at intervention vs. placebo or no additional intervention. The issue here relates more to risk of bias rather than the meta-analytic technique. There is no problem combining these two trial designs in one meta-analysis, but lack of blinding could be a source of statistical heterogeneity (if present in the analysis). It's also important to keep in mind that not all placebos are the same (e.g. injection vs. pill) and a lot of studies don't report adequately on the properties of placebos for the reviewer to be confident of it's use. In other words, just because a study is reported to be a double-blind, placebo-controlled trial doesn't mean that it was set up and conducted properly to prevent patients, personnel and outcome assessors to be blinded to intervention. Have a look at the Cochrane Handbook for Systematic Reviewers on more details guidance (cochrane-handbook.org).

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Approaches differ on this. Some people advocate selecting only the best studies (which means placebo-controlled but also meeting other criteria). The idea is that those studies provide the best measure of the actual benefit of the treatment and combining them will give us the best possible estimate. This was in fact the standard approach prior to the development of meta-analysis techniques (as part of qualitative reviews doing implicit “vote counting”).

Others would rather include as many study as possible *but also include quality indicators* in the model to test for potential method effects. Here, the idea is that if some particular aspect of the methodology does alter the results, we can find out, but if it doesn't we have the broadest possible empirical basis to estimate the effect. There is also no need to rely on arbitrary exclusion criteria or to argue endlessly about what a “good” study is, we can have a data-based approach to quality issues.

In practice, the second approach seems interesting but it's more work and, depending on what you want to do with your meta-analysis, you might need to prepare yourself to defend this choice carefully because there are often people who react very negatively to this idea.

Gene Glass wrote [a text that touches upon these issues](http://www.gvglass.info/papers/meta25.html).